# I want to read a live log file and want to search for some specific keyword which I make on runtime

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm very new to "threading" and don't know how to use it. 
I did use to create a new Thread for every test case, and those threads were never terminated.
Single keyword search is also working fine for me but things get messed up when I create a new keyword every time for a new thread.

Junit Test:

```
public class Test{

    @Test
    public static void someTest() {

        SSH ssh = new SSH();

        // test logic
        String key = "some_value from test logic";

        ssh.start(key);
    }
}
```

The `SSH` Thread:

```
public class SSH extends Thread {
    String key = "";

    public void run {
        ssh(key);
    }

    public SSH(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }


    public static void ssh(String key) {
        // some logic
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first a `Thread` is for executing code while other code will run on. It is like you say one person should count from 0 to 100 and another person should say the ABC. This is not possible without threads.

---

Reading a live log file is a problem that can be solved with threads.

Using a thread that looks like this:

```
public class SSHThread extends Thread {

    private String key;
    private volatile boolean endFlag;

    public SSHThread(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    // stops thread from executing
    public void stop() {
        endFlag = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // pre logic

        while (true) {    // runs infinitely
            if (endFlag) {
                break;

                // could also be 'return;' if there is no 'post logic'
            }

            ssh(key);
        }

        // post logic
    }
}
```

This thread runs forever until the programm is stopped so it is a good idea to call `stop()` before exiting the programm. This thread should do everthing you need.

Maybe if you need it, set `endFlag` to `true` or call `stop()` in `ssh()`.

---

**Some lecture**

[What is a "thread" (really)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201852/what-is-a-thread-really)

[Java read a logfile live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886202/java-read-a-logfile-live)

[How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

[Threads in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865315/threads-in-java)

[What does 'synchronized' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean)

[What is the volatile keyword useful for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for)

[Avoid Deadlock example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326861/avoid-deadlock-example)